# C# MVC Core Customize Bootstrap CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core

I created a new MVC Core Project from the Visual Studio templates. I would like to customize the bootstrap css files provided. In Bootstrap, it says "Have an existing configuration? Upload your config.json to import it." 
Where is the config.json file from the Visual Studio MVC? I see the bootstrap.css, however does not locate the config.json file. I want to format the template webpages.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Thank you,

Comment: What does this mean: *it says "Have an existing configuration?"* ? When do you get this message?

Comment: if you click on customize bootstrap link, you will see the message

Comment: I guess Visual studio uses the full version of bootstrap, not a custom one, therefore there is no bootstrap config json file

Comment: thanks, how did you derive this? "Visual studio uses the full version of bootstrap",  thats what I thought, VS uses the original full version of Boostrap, would like to validate with a proof or source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio's template doesn't include a "config.json" file for Bootstrap. That file is part of your download once you've setup your custom Bootstrap download on the website.

Seems worth noting that the custom download option doesn't exist for Bootstrap 4, and the v3 customizer will be going away at some point. From v4 onward, you're expected to use the Sass version if you want to customize Bootstrap.

There are both Less and Sass versions of v3, found on the [Getting Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) page, which would also allow you to consistently customize Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in the template project generated by Visual studio 2017, **it uses the full version of bootstrap**, not a custom one, therefore **there is no bootstrap config.json** file.

In other words, in your case you will not be using an existing version of config.json, but rather you will need to create a new one.

Comment: @BlueLamp82, it is because you can find the whole bootstrap css file in the wwwroot folder in you project. It may be a customized version, but at least it seems to be a very big file (which indicates that VS2017 uses the whole bunch of bootstrap css rules). In addition, there is no such json file for bootstrap (which you are asking for). Is it clear now?